# Risks of Caffeine Powder

Tags: caffeine, drug-metabolism, coffee

I'm genetically predisposed to early onset osteoporosis, so I'm trying to cut back on acids in my diet. Coffee is a big one, but I'm also still in school so I'm very attached to caffeine. Would switching from coffee to caffeine powder have any health risks?

I own and can use a milligram scale to measure the caffeine, so I'm not worried about measuring out safe doses. I would try to intake roughly the same amount of caffeine that I would by drinking coffee, so the amount of caffeine would not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caffeine comes from **coffee beans**, but it can also be synthesized in a laboratory.

## Caffeine has the same structure whether it’s in Coffee, Energy Drinks, Tea or pills/powder.

Caffeine dosages should be tailored to individuals. If you are new to caffeine supplements then the usual recommended start is with a 100mg dose (**see warning below)**. Typically, 200mg of caffeine is used for fat-burning supplementation (impact is still being discussed in scientific community), while acute strength increases occur at higher doses, 500mg and above (again, still under discussion). Researchers tend to use a dosage range of 4-6mg/kg bodyweight.

The structure is the same but its easier to take more than you are used to if you measure wrong. I would **personally** suggest you **avoid powder** and go for **pill form** if you are set on reducing intake through less coffee.

[You can read more about caffeine over at Examine.com](http://examine.com/supplements/Caffeine/)

---

**Caution Notice**

Caffeine is highly stimulatory and a systemic vasoconstrictor. Caution should be exerted if one is either not used to caffeine ingestion or currently has high blood pressure.

Caffeine should not be used as a supplement in those with cardiac impairments without prior consultation of one's doctor.

Caffeine can also have an effect on ones quality of sleep; while you may be able to fall asleep, it will be of inferior quality.

*Note:* Habitual caffeine use leads to tolerance. This means the effects of caffeine will be diminished, often to the point where the only benefit a user experiences is caffeine’s anti-sleep effect. This is an ‘insurmountable’ tolerance, which means more caffeine will not overcome it. [A month-long break from caffeine will reduce tolerance](http://examine.com/nutrition/do-i-need-to-cycle-caffeine/).

Comment: I'd add that caffeine doesn't come from coffee beans per se. I believe tea also has it? But for mass production coffee (robusta) is probably the most efficient.